# filename does not match the pattern in the case construct of a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

My goal for this program was to efficiently rearrange the random file in a directory and place then in their respective sub directories based on their formats that is audio files are placed in the audios directory and so on. so far the pattern to match this files does not yield the required results and all the files are being moved to the others directory.

here is the code

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the path of the current directory
CURR_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)";
# SCRIPT_NAME="$(basename "${BASE_SOURCE[0]}")"
SCRIPT_NAME="$(basename "$0")"

echo "$SCRIPT_NAME"
# List the various file format and thier extensions 
LIST_DOCS=("doc" "docx" "pdf" "txt")
LIST_IMAGES=("jpg" "jpeg" "png" "gif")
LIST_AUDIOS=("mp3" "wav" "ogg" "aac" "m4a" "mp4" "wma" "aiff" "au" "vox")
LIST_VIDEOS=("mp4" "avi" "mov" "wmv" "mpeg" "mpg" "m4v" "mkv" "flv" "webm")

# Check if the images, videos, audios and documents directory exist
for dir_name in images videos documents audios others; do 
    if [ ! -d "$CURR_DIR/$dir_name" ]; then
        mkdir "$CURR_DIR/$dir_name"
    fi
done

# Read all the files and sort them
for file in "$CURR_DIR"/*
do 
    # Check if the current file is not the script itself
    if [ "$file" = "$CURR_DIR/$SCRIPT_NAME" ]; then 
        continue
    fi

    if [ -d "$file" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    # Move the file to the destination directory
    case "$file" in 
        *."${LIST_DOCS}")
            echo "Moving $file to documents/"
            mv $file "$CURR_DIR/documents/"
            ;;
        *."${LIST_IMAGES}")
            echo "Moving $file to documents/"
            mv $file "$CURR_DIR/images/"
            ;;
        *."${LIST_VIDEOS}")
            echo "Moving $file to documents/"
            mv $file "$CURR_DIR/videos/"
            ;;
        *."${LIST_AUDIOS}")
            echo "Moving $file to documents/"
            mv $file "$CURR_DIR/audios/"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Moving $file to documents/"
            mv "$file" "$CURR_DIR/others"
            ;;
    esac

done

echo -e "Your files are now sorted :) \nProcess terminated"
```

I re-adjusted the pattern at the level of the case construct to match the files to a pattern that included a wildcard at the prefix and a list that holds all the various extensions belonging to a particular format such as audio or email

`*."${LIST_DOCS}` was the pattern i used

Comment: btw, `$(basename "$0")` is considerably slower to run than `${0##*/}` (the former requires starting up the separate `basename` executable, the latter is built into bash). And consider following POSIX convention to use lowercase names for your own variables to avoid overwriting all-caps special/shell-builtin variables by mistake -- see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable.

Comment: As for the question directly asked -- `${LIST_DOCS}` evaluates to `${LIST_DOCS[0]}`; it ignores everything but the very first array element. Bash doesn't have any construct that does exactly what you want -- `*."${LIST_DOCS[@]}"` would evaluate to `*.'doc' 'docx' 'pdf' 'txt'`, with the `*.` only coming before `doc` -- so you'll want to iterate over the array explicitly.

Comment: _Personally_, I'd use an associative array mapping extensions to directory names; no need for a case statement at all that way.

Comment: Perhaps I'd use `mv *.{doc,docx",pdf,txt} documents` or `docs='doc\|docx\|pdf\|txt'; find  -type f -regex ".*\($docs\)" -exec mv {} documents`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, you mention shell does not have a construct to does what i want exactly,  how can i use the associative array mapping extension?

Comment: The thing is an associative array. The use case is to map file extensions to directory names. Mapping strings to other strings is what associative arrays do, so look up their syntax and you'll see how they work. If there's an aspect that isn't obvious after you've done the initial research, explain how/why it's unclear and I'll follow up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fellow devs, After a while of carefully reviewing all what you guys told me, i was able to come out with the desired result using the ideas you all gave me.
Here is the new shell script with the desired implementation

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check for correct usage
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <folder>"
    exit 1
fi

# Get the path of the current directory
# CURR_DIR="$(pwd)"
CURR_DIR="$1"
SCRIPT_NAME="$(basename "$0")"

echo "$SCRIPT_NAME"

# List the various file format and their extensions
LIST_DOCS=("doc" "docx" "pdf" "txt")
LIST_IMAGES=("jpg" "jpeg" "png" "gif")
LIST_AUDIOS=("mp3" "wav" "ogg" "aac" "m4a" "mp4" "wma" "aiff" "au" "vox")
LIST_VIDEOS=("mp4" "avi" "mov" "wmv" "mpeg" "mpg" "m4v" "mkv" "flv" "webm")

# Check and create directories if they don't exist
for dir_name in images videos documents audios others; do
    if [ ! -d "$CURR_DIR/$dir_name" ]; then
        mkdir -p "$CURR_DIR/$dir_name"
    fi
done

# Read all the files and sort them
for file in "$CURR_DIR"/*; do
    # Check if the current file is not the script itself or a directory
    if [ "$file" = "$CURR_DIR/$SCRIPT_NAME" ] || [ -d "$file" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    # Get the file extension in lowercase
    ext="${file##*.}"

    # get lowercase so you can handle all cases well
    ext_lc="${ext,,}"

    # Move the file to the destination directory
    matched=false
    for ext_list in "${LIST_DOCS[@]}"; do
        if [ "$ext_lc" = "$ext_list" ]; then
            matched=true
            echo "Moving $file to documents/"
            mv "$file" "$CURR_DIR/documents/"
            break
        fi
    done

    if ! "$matched"; then
        for ext_list in "${LIST_IMAGES[@]}"; do
            if [ "$ext_lc" = "$ext_list" ]; then
                matched=true
                echo "Moving $file to images/"
                mv "$file" "$CURR_DIR/images/"
                break
            fi
        done
    fi

    if ! "$matched"; then
        for ext_list in "${LIST_AUDIOS[@]}"; do
            if [ "$ext_lc" = "$ext_list" ]; then
                matched=true
                echo "Moving $file to audios/"
                mv "$file" "$CURR_DIR/audios/"
                break
            fi
        done
    fi

    if ! "$matched"; then
        for ext_list in "${LIST_VIDEOS[@]}"; do
            if [ "$ext_lc" = "$ext_list" ]; then
                matched=true
                echo "Moving $file to videos/"
                mv "$file" "$CURR_DIR/videos/"
                break
            fi
        done
    fi

    if ! "$matched"; then
        echo "Moving $file to others/"
        mv "$file" "$CURR_DIR/others/"
    fi
done

echo -e "Your files are now sorted :)\nProcess terminated"
```

I used a loop to check the various extensions and placed them in their desired sub-directories.

Answer (score 2):

> Referencing an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to referencing with a subscript of 0. Any reference to a variable using a valid subscript is legal, and bash will create an array if necessary.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html

So your first case actually checks only for `*.doc`.

To archive your goal you could loop over the arrays to see if the extensions match. You can get the file extension from a filename with only bash with something like `${filename##*.}`. (removes anything from value of variable filename until and including the last dot)